# List of generic objects as request body in retrofit 2 and Gson

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

I am trying retrofit 2 for the first time as part of a global refactoring of my app.

My app stores data of different king it reads from sensors. Each measure has common features, so I created a parent Measure class (which is not abstract) and a few subclasses for every kind of data I need. For example, I created a TemperatureMeasure subclass.

I have access to a public API that I can't change to send the measures I collect in my app.

Using retrofit (2.0 beta), I declared an interface with this method :

```
@POST("/bdd/measure/send/{measureType}/{sensorId}")
Call<APIResponse> sendFludiaRaw(@Path("site") String siteId, @Path("measureType") String measureType, @Path("sensor") String sensorId, @Body List<? extends Measure> measures);
```

My plan was to be able to call this method by providing a List of objects extending the Measure class.
I am using the Gson converter as the serializer.
When I call this method - for example with a list of TemperatureMeasure objects - the created JSON objects only include the members of the Measure class but nothing from the TemperatureMeasure members.

What would be the best solution to fix this ?

From what I've been reading, one option would be to implement a serializer/deserializer and provide it to the Gson converter. That serializer would automatically try to serialize the correct subclass when it comes across a Measure object.
Another option would be handle serialization myself using Gson, and provide the raw JSON data to the retrofit call as a String, but that would kind of ruin the nice aspects of using Retrofit.
The last option I found was to create a request for each kind of measure in my retrofit interface.

Is there a nicer generic-friendly option that would keep me from writing a giant switch statement somewhere ?

Thanks